# how to extract substring redshift, postgres

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have problem with extracting a substring from a column.

I need extract a number, which is between two strings: `<=>` and `level[highlighted]`

I used something like this:

```
split_part(SPLIT_PART(mycolumn, '<=>', 2), '<br>level[highlighted]', 1)
```

but there is a problem because string `<=>` is contained several times in one row (but the string `<br>level[highlighted]` is only once in every row).

Comment: Could you please Edit your question and supply several sample input values for `mycolumn`? We need to see the input data to be provide the write formula. Also, could you please clarify -- are you using PostgreSQL, or are you using Amazon Redshift? The answer might differ between the two systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to match and extract data:

**Postgres**

```sql
with _t as (
    select 'foo<=>bar<=>123<br>level[highlighted]'::text as col
)
select
    substring(col, '<=>(\d+)<br>level\[highlighted\]')
from
    _t
;
```

Where `(\d+)` is a match group for (1 or more) digits; the result would be:

```
 substring
-----------
 123
(1 row)
```

---

**Redshift**

Similar results can be achieved with [`regexp_substr()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html).